# Remove Duplicate Occurance of Values in SQL Server Select Record

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
Date    Time    Event   site
2017-03-29  13:09:31.0000000    IN  Old Site
2017-03-29  14:26:32.0000000    OUT Old Site
2017-03-29  14:41:02.0000000    IN  Old Site
2017-03-29  16:21:17.0000000    OUT Old Site
2017-03-29  16:54:18.0000000    IN  Old Site
2017-03-29  16:54:24.0000000    IN  Old Site
2017-03-29  17:45:05.0000000    OUT Old Site
2017-03-29  19:30:03.0000000    IN  Old Site
```

---

```
DECLARE @empTime TABLE ([Date] DATE,[Time] TIME,[Event] VARCHAR(30),[Site] VARCHAR(30))

INSERT INTO @empTime ([Date],[Time],[Event],[Site])
VALUES
('2017-03-29', '13:09:31.0000000', 'IN', 'Old Site'),
('2017-03-29', '14:26:32.0000000', 'OUT', 'Old Site'),
('2017-03-29', '14:41:02.0000000', 'IN', 'Old Site'),
('2017-03-29', '16:21:17.0000000', 'OUT', 'Old Site'),
('2017-03-29', '16:54:18.0000000', 'IN', 'Old Site'),
('2017-03-29', '16:54:24.0000000', 'IN', 'Old Site'),
('2017-03-29', '17:45:05.0000000', 'OUT', 'Old Site'),
('2017-03-29', '19:30:03.0000000', 'IN', 'Old Site')

SELECT *
FROM @empTime
```

As per above code and output, I want to remove one of the Record for `'IN' '16:54:24.0000000'` because I want record in form of continuous `IN-OUT-IN-OUT`.

I want to remove duplicate occurrence of value in below record. I want record should be in continuous form `i.e. In-Out-In-Out.`

Comment: Please show us what you tried

Comment: Moving forward let's copy past some consumable code instead of providing a screenshot.

Comment: How it's possible `31:44` & `29:47` data in time format ? Please clear more your question here

Comment: @BasantMishra You want only 2 records from this 1st is First IN and 2nd is Last Out ? OR You want all this records but with sequence of IN-OUT ?

Comment: There is a tag called `gaps-and-islands`, check out previous questions with that tag and see if that helps you.

Comment: I want In-Out sequence for all record. But I want to remove one record if any double entry for same record. Means I want IN-OUT-IN-OUT. 
In this process, I and to remove one of the old value after first IN and so on.

Comment: So you want to delete the record from this table? Or just select the table without the record? If it's delete - what is the primary key on this table?

Comment: I want to select from this table with above mentioned sequence. i.e IN-OUT-IN-OUT

Answer (score 0):

We're going to operate under the assumption that you want IN-OUT-IN-OUT... in the order of the time. I manually created data from your prev screenshot BTW:

```
--What your sample data should look like next time
-------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @yourtable TABLE
(
  employeeCode int, 
  [shift]      varchar(40),
  [Date]       date,
  [time]       time,
  [Event]      varchar(3),
  [Site]       varchar(10)
);

DECLARE 
  @empcode int         = 561, 
  @shift   varchar(40) = '1PM - 10PM',
  @date    date        = '3/28/2017',
  @site    varchar(10) = 'Old Site';

INSERT @yourtable 
VALUES 
(@empcode, @shift, @date, '00:04:47.0', 'IN',  @site),
(@empcode, @shift, @date, '00:08:38.0', 'OUT', @site),
(@empcode, @shift, @date, '00:08:41.0', 'OUT', @site),
(@empcode, @shift, @date, '00:19:44.0', 'IN',  @site),
(@empcode, @shift, @date, '00:20:25.0', 'OUT', @site),
(@empcode, @shift, @date, '00:20:50.0', 'IN',  @site),
(@empcode, @shift, @date, '00:21:21.0', 'OUT', @site),
(@empcode, @shift, @date, '00:29:47.0', 'IN',  @site),
(@empcode, @shift, @date, '00:29:53.0', 'IN',  @site),
(@empcode, @shift, @date, '00:36:52.0', 'OUT', @site);

-- A solution:
-------------------------------------------------------
WITH prep AS
(
  SELECT *, 
    lag1 = LAG([Event], 1) 
          OVER (PARTITION BY employeeCode, [shift], [Date], [site] ORDER BY [time])
  FROM @yourtable
)
SELECT 
    employeeCode
    [shift],
    [Date],
    [time],
    [Event],
    [Site]
FROM prep
WHERE [Event] <> lag1;
```

**Results:**

```
shift       Date       time             Event Site
----------- ---------- ---------------- ----- ----------
561         2017-03-28 00:08:38.0000000 OUT   Old Site
561         2017-03-28 00:19:44.0000000 IN    Old Site
561         2017-03-28 00:20:25.0000000 OUT   Old Site
561         2017-03-28 00:20:50.0000000 IN    Old Site
561         2017-03-28 00:21:21.0000000 OUT   Old Site
561         2017-03-28 00:29:47.0000000 IN    Old Site
561         2017-03-28 00:36:52.0000000 OUT   Old Site
```

Comment: LAG function is not working in SQL Server 2008. Any alternative to LAG in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. As per your request this should work in SQL Server 2008

```
;WITH cte_empTime([Date], [Time], [Event], [Site]) AS
(
SELECT '2017-03-29','13:09:31.0000000', 'IN',   'Old Site' UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-03-29','14:26:32.0000000', 'OUT',  'Old Site' UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-03-29','14:41:02.0000000', 'IN',   'Old Site' UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-03-29','16:21:17.0000000', 'OUT',  'Old Site' UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-03-29','16:54:18.0000000', 'IN',   'Old Site' UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-03-29','16:54:24.0000000', 'IN',   'Old Site' UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-03-29','17:45:05.0000000', 'OUT',  'Old Site' UNION ALL
SELECT '2017-03-29','19:30:03.0000000', 'IN',   'Old Site'
),
cte_SeqGenerater AS 
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date],[Time]) AS SeqID,
    [Date],
    [Time],
    [Event],
    [Site]
FROM cte_empTime
)
SELECT a.[Date],
    a.[Time],
    a.[Event],
    a.[Site]
FROM cte_SeqGenerater a
LEFT JOIN cte_SeqGenerater b
    ON a.SeqID = b.SeqID + 1
WHERE CASE 
        WHEN a.[Event] = b.[Event] THEN 0
        ELSE 1
      END = 1
```

### Result

```
+ ------------------------------------------------ +
| Date       | Time             | Event | Site     |
+ ---------- | ---------------- | ----- | -------- +
| 2017-03-29 | 13:09:31.0000000 | IN    | Old Site |
| 2017-03-29 | 14:26:32.0000000 | OUT   | Old Site |
| 2017-03-29 | 14:41:02.0000000 | IN    | Old Site |
| 2017-03-29 | 16:21:17.0000000 | OUT   | Old Site |
| 2017-03-29 | 16:54:18.0000000 | IN    | Old Site |
| 2017-03-29 | 17:45:05.0000000 | OUT   | Old Site |
| 2017-03-29 | 19:30:03.0000000 | IN    | Old Site |
+ ------------------------------------------------ +
```

Comment: This is working perfectly for now. Thanks for response and help.

Comment: Happy to help @BasantMishra

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @empTime TABLE ([Id] Integer,[Date] DATE,[Time] TIME,[Event] VARCHAR(30),[Site] VARCHAR(30))

INSERT INTO @empTime ([Id],[Date],[Time],[Event],[Site])
VALUES
(1,'2017-03-29', '13:09:31.0000000', 'IN', 'Old Site'),
(2,'2017-03-29', '14:26:32.0000000', 'OUT', 'Old Site'),
(3,'2017-03-29', '14:41:02.0000000', 'IN', 'Old Site'),
(4,'2017-03-29', '16:21:17.0000000', 'OUT', 'Old Site'),
(5,'2017-03-29', '16:54:18.0000000', 'IN', 'Old Site'),
(6,'2017-03-29', '16:54:24.0000000', 'IN', 'Old Site'),
(7,'2017-03-29', '17:45:05.0000000', 'OUT', 'Old Site'),
(8,'2017-03-29', '19:30:03.0000000', 'IN', 'Old Site')

SELECT *
FROM @empTime

Select *  from @empTime where Id not in (Select top(1) Id from @empTime where (Id % 2) = 0 and [Event]!='Out')
```

Comment: you have only two option in give case either use RowNumber use odd even logic or use Id field which should not be delete physically from database.